# Using Symfony 6, I am not able to inject the Entity Manager into a service constructor

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have a class Dbg defined like this:

```
namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\Debug;
use App\Repository\DebugRespository;
use App\Repository\SettingRespository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
class Dbg
{
    private $em = null;
    
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
...
}
```

I am using the default dependency injection and it seems to work in other services, but this one is giving an error "Too few arguments to function App\Service\Dbg::__construct(), 0 passed in ..." when I instantiate the Dbg class like this:

```
$dbg = new Dbg();
```

My services.yaml looks like this:

```
services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
_defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    bind:
 

# makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
        - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
        - '../src/Entity/'
        - '../src/Kernel.php'
```

Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Using Dependency Injection is the opposite of manually instantiating a class instance. You either use one or the other, not both. If you choose to use DI, then the class instance becomes available for use in the container. You can then Inject _that_ service into other classes to use it. If you manually instantiate the class, then you must include all the arguments yourself.

Comment: So I am trying to inject the EntityManagerInterface into the DBG class. Are you saying I have to also inject the Dbg class into other controllers to use it in that way?

Comment: Yes, it's fine if your Dbg class is using autowiring to inject the entity manager, you should also use the service injection to use Dbg and not instantiate it yourself

Comment: You have to inject the new Dbg service in constructor or in action. If you inject EntityManager to use a specific repository, i suggest you to directly inject the repository

Comment: BTW, thanks Dylan for the answer, that was the correct answer and it is working fine now.